# Strange keyboard media key behavior

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows-media-player

The play/pause/stop buttons work fine on Google Play music (web client), but not in Windows Media Player or Groove.  This problem occurs independent of the keyboard.  My USB and laptop keyboards have identical behavior.  All other buttons on the keyboards work as designed (volume control, mute, calculator, home page, etc.)

What I've tried:

- I've deleted and re-installed all keyboards in the Device Manager
- Human Interface Device service is running and set to automatically start

Is there some driver specific to just those specific playback functions that I'm missing on my machine?  And why would Google Music on the web still function properly?

Comment: What windows version?

Comment: Windows 10.....

Comment: And what keyboard you have?

Comment: Dell laptop and dell keyboard with media controls.  But the problem, as I mentioned above, is keyboard independent.

Comment: Would you [come](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162851/strange-keyboard-media-key-behavior) and explain?

Comment: Can you try and login with a different profile? Sounds to me like some program is interfering with the keyboard behaviour, If not succesful Start with some startup programs disabled and see how it works, have you tried your usb keyboard in another PC?

Comment: Yes, USB keyboard works fine.  I'll try logging out later when I can

Comment: Also try google play on the web with different browsers and let us know results, I can almost be sure It will fail with MS browsers since they will pickup the keyboard from the same service as groove or media player.

Comment: @arana You were correct that IE ignores those buttons.  Tried to create a new account but this computer is locked down (work machine).  Now checking for startup programs and removing other keyboards/drivers that were installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!  My Google Music Chrome extension was working great because it was eating the media key events. Once I un-installed the extension, the other media applications could get the media key events.  I found the answer here on a Spotify forum:

[Media Keys No Longer Work](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Media-keys-no-longer-work/td-p/807591)